# module has no attribute 'Twitter'

Tags: python, twitter

[ScreenShot with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPo1W.jpg) Can someone help me with this?

```
>>> import twitter
>>> twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(domain="api.twitter.com", api_version='1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Twitter'
```

Comment: Have you named the script you are working on `twitter.py`? Name it something else. It's trying to import from that file.

Comment: Sorry, but I just started learning this things so I do not understand your question... I did not change any name... i just used easy_install networkx, numpy and twitter in cmd ...
The only file that I can find is python_twitter-3.0rc1-py3.5.egg

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I should clarify.  Based on the package release version in your screenshot it appears you have installed this package:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter/3.0rc1

Which is different from the package you intended to install:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter/1.17.1

You need to uninstall the package you had (e.g., `pip freeze`, `pip uninstall`) and install the correct one (`pip install twitter==1.17.1`).  I highly recommend you discontinue using easy_install.

Comment: Yes, I have this one... but is not working even if I try just the command twitter -h